# Azure indirect Peering

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

Let's say I have peering set up as follows: A<->B<->C and want to route traffic between vnet A and C

Is this currently possible? Perhaps a vnet gateway in B & the usage of UDR's?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, it is not possible.

**VNet peering is between two virtual networks, and there is no derived transitive relationship.** If virtual network A is peered with virtual network B, and if virtual network B is peered with virtual network C, it does not translate to virtual network A being peered with virtual network C. [UDR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-udr-overview) could not achieve your scenario.

Why not set up as follows: A <->B B<->C A<->C?

More information about Peering please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview).

Comment: But am I right in saying it could be achieved if I had a virtual appliance in B? I could make the next hop the virtual appliance and then it would handle the routing from there?

Comment: Azure does not support this. Peering route depends on Azure.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but doesn't the second diagram on this page basically describe what I'm saying?

Comment: Sorry, left out the link and can't edit the post. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-udr-overview