# Azure Vnet Peering

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

Can someone let me know when Microsoft Azure introduced Vnet Peering? I'm working with a company that has introduced a number of Vnets (8 Vnets) for security. I'm trying to suggest that creating that number of Vnets is unnecessary.

I just would like to know if there are any other benefits to Vnet peering and when it was first introduced by Azure?

Cheers

Carlton

Comment: Hi Community, I have just found out in was introduced in September 2016

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just would like to know if there are any other benefits to Vnet
> peering and when it was first introduced by Azure?

Virtual network peering enables you to connect two virtual networks in the same region through the Azure backbone network. Once peered, the two virtual networks appear as one, for connectivity purposes. The two virtual networks are still managed as separate resources, but virtual machines in the peered virtual networks can communicate with each other directly, by using private IP addresses. More information about this please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview).

> I'm trying to suggest that creating that number of Vnets is
> unnecessary.

It depends on your company's need. If you want to connect two Vnets, you must create a peering tunnel.

**VNet peering is between two virtual networks, and there is no derived transitive relationship.**

In others words, if you want 3 VNets to be both interconnected, you need create 3  peering tunnels. Please refer to the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265926/azure-indirect-peering/41274650#41274650).

Comment: Using peering, you don't need pay for VPN gateway cost and you could connect two VNets.

Answer (score 1):

We announced peering in September 2016. See our service update for reference: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/vnet-peering-ga/

VNet peering has many benefits: low latency, high bandwidth, direct VM to VM connectivity among others. You can see a comprehensive list here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview

You can also suggest using subnets in the same virtual network: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-create-vnet-arm-pportal

-- Anavi N [MSFT]